# How to get an unique ID nested inside of the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some `<tr>` elements with unique IDs.

```
<tr id="683535">some code</tr>
<tr id="683536">some code</tr>
<tr id="683537">some code</tr>
```

I want users to click on `<tr>`, after what a js function will be called. And I need to get this ID inside of current function without using events like `<tr onclick=""`. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event listener you should have a variable for the event.

Example:

```
$("body").on("click", "tr", function(e){
  var row = $(this);
  console.debug(row); //Should print clicked TR
  console.info(row.attr("id")); //Should print the ID
});
```

Comment: Better to use `this` . The `target` will likely not be the actual `<tr>` and more likely it's `<td>` children

Comment: Why would you add the click handler on the `body`?

Comment: It's just an example. This practice is called "delegation". It's useful when, for instance, the content you want to listen for is added to the DOM after the event listener is created.

Comment: I know event delegation. The question is, why at the top of the document (`body`) and not the closest reasonable (`table`) :)

Comment: The entire table could be added after the event listener declaration...It was just an example, I don't understand why bothering..

Comment: yeap, I got it was just a simple example. I've altered 'body' to that element I needed

Comment: @Lab Lab Yes, I was answering to Andreas

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
$('tr').on('click',function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Can i restrict the `tr` by some id or class? like this:
`$('#someId tr').on('click', fucntion(){});`

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want events, than your only way to interact with browser is classic hyperlink with `<a>` tag, where you can also include js functions like `<a href="javascript:doStuff(uid);">do stuff with your uid</a>` so you can simply generate such hrefs for each row inside your row generator.

Comment: This is 2017 not 1997. Unobtrusive javascript is considered best practice these days. Not to mention there is no need for an `<a>` tag to do this inline

Comment: Unless telekinesis is developed, only events and hyperlink clicks are the way you interact with browser, so if question is not to use events, than hyperlinks is all you have ;-)

Comment: Where does it say anything about not using events? If browser supports using javascript....then basic events will also be supported. This is not the stone age

Comment: Just read the question: "And I need to get this ID inside of current function **without using events like <tr onclick="". **" ;-)